# Find the Current Session Id in Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

How do you find the current Session Id on the client?

I am able to get what seems like the last session id, not the current session id.

```
console.log(Meteor.default_connection._lastSessionId)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The wording for this is a bit confusing, but `_lastSessionId` is the current session id.

It is only called this because if the client is disconnected and seeks to reconnect it wants to re-establish the session with the last session id.

The client would reconnect with a message like this :

```
{"msg": "connect ", "session": "ERoZSR3R3f8zBQ6Ry", "version": "pre1","support":["pre1"]}
```

The `session` uses the lastSessionId value. This is then used to re-establish the previous connection.

This is the only case where a new session id would be assigned on a reconnection. That or the session is expired off the server.

If the server restarts it's cache is refreshed and it wouldn't recognize the session anymore, and a new session id would be assigned.

Comment: After restarting the server (via a hot code reload), the client reconnects with a different `_lastSessionId` rather than using the same one as before the server restart. Is the `_lastSessionId` supposed to remain the same as mentioned?

Answer (score 2):

The Meteor login token by default is stored in local storage (not in cookie).

On the client you could access

```
token = Meteor._localStorage.getItem('Meteor.loginToken')
```

On the server, once token is received, use the Accounts api to hash using

```
Accounts._hashLoginToken(res.req.body.token)
```

Then, you could validate hashed value against users collection for `services.resume.loginTokens.hashedToken` field

**This hack can be used to build meteor - express integration**

[image: Meteor Login Token]