# Meteor server-side-only session

Tags: meteor

Is there a way to store information specific to the current connection on the server like a session?

something like would be usefull

```
if(Meteor.isServer){
   Session.set('something-only-server-side-for-current-connection', 'hello');
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is your use case?  You don't want to use Session (Client side only).

Comment: we need some server-side-only object, where it is possible to transfer some data from a publish-function (session.set) to collection.allow (session.get)

Comment: I'd advice against using `collection.allow`.  Use `Meteor.Methods` for all collection updates.  Are you trying to identify the user?  [this.userId](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/method_userId) is the best way to do this (will work in both your `publish` function, and in `Meteor.Methods`

Comment: Thank you JeremyK, but the user is not identified and unknown. this.userId will not work in this scenario. Why do you think that collection.allow/deny is not a good idea? How should an update on a published collection work with Meteor.Methods?

Comment: when you use `allow/deny`, and then `.update` / etc on the server, it's still going through meteor methods, just not ones you define explicitly.  And given that It's actually more difficult to get the security right with `allow/deny` than in a method you define, I'd always recommend using `meteor methods`.  [Here's a related link](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/allow-deny-a-security-primer/).

Comment: Anyway this is still discussing an implementation detail, not use case.  I take it you are subscribing to a collection (with a parameter? ) and want to store the parameter on the server and check against it when there are operations on the collection?

Comment: yes, with a parameter

Comment: `this.connection` is available in both [publish functions](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/publish_connection), and [meteor methods](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/method_connection).  Create another (unpublished) collection on the server (or other key-value store) to store associated parameters with the connection.  Create a [`onStop`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/publish_onstop) callback to cleanup the server side collection.

Comment: Here is a package that does something similar to what I suggested above:  [erasaur:server-session](https://atmospherejs.com/erasaur/server-session)

Comment: @JeremyK: can you add your "this.connection.." text as an answer? In this way i can accept it as the solution. Regarding the security: does using meteor methods mean to deny all access and call the method from the client? In this case, the user would not be able to insert/update offline i think. Is synchronization lost then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.connection` is available in both [publish functions](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/publish_connection), and [meteor methods](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/method_connection).

Create another (unpublished) collection on the server (or you can use another key-value store) to store associated parameters with the connection. Create a [onStop callback](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/publish_onstop) to cleanup the server side collection (or do this periodically).

[erasaur:server-session](https://atmospherejs.com/erasaur/server-session) is a package that looks to be doing something very similar to the above.

Comment: you can also get the 'connection' in allow/deny with `DDP._CurrentInvocation.get().connection`

Answer (score 2):

I would create a collection called *UserSessions* (or similar) and put whatever you need into it indexed by `Meteor.default_connection._lastSessionId` which turns out to be the *current* sessionId [[reference]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21086055/2805154).

```
UserSessions.insert({ sessionId: Meteor.default_connection._lastSessionId,
  createdAt: new Date(), key1: value, key2: value, ...});
```

Make sure you index-unique `sessionId` for performance. You can also purge old sessions from time-to-time based on the `createdAt` timestamp.